# Documenting parameters with long descriptions in Sphinx

Tags: python, parameters, python-sphinx

I'm documenting my Python classes using Sphinx, and sometimes I want to give my parameters quite long descriptions to explain something in details. Unfortunately, Sphinx generates ugly output for me which wastes a lot of space and breaks the whole page appearance:

[image: Before]

It can be seen that Sphinx creates a table, then puts "Parameters" header to the left cell, and the actual list of parameters to the right cell. But there should be way to avoid creating this table completely. After playing with the page DOM tree I finally can show that I want to achieve:

[image: After]

Is there a built-in way to do this or I'd have to create a PR to Sphinx theme or Sphinx itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting [an issue](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2098) to Sphinx bug-tracker and having no response, I've decided to roll-out my own solution (better say, hack). To achieve the look I want, I have written a simple Sphinx extension which post-processes generated HTML code. It can be found on PyPI:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib.divparams
- https://pythonhosted.org/sphinxcontrib.divparams/

This doesn't seem to be the best way to solve the issue, but the behaviour I wanted to change is deeply hard-coded in `docutils`, not Sphinx.